# ubuntu server - different sessions

Tags: ubuntu-9.04

It will sound crazy, but I don't get it.

I installed 2x ubuntu servers 9.04 and sometimes after restart I have different
hostname and changes I made 30 min ago before restart are gone. I even moved files, 
created new folders, changed different services but none of these things were "saved".

I use encrypted home folder for my test user. I had my configuration done but now 
on one server I went back 2 hrs of work.

Does anyone have an idea what's happening ?

Comment: Is this running under a virtual machine of any sorts?  Is it on a RAID 5 system?

Comment: it's on a RAID 1.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere, somehow, your changes are not being written to disk.  Without additional information, it will be hard to determine what the root cause of it is.

How many drives is the system configured for?  What is the configuration of the drives themselves? (I see you mentioned it's a RAID-1).  Is it software or hardware RAID?  Is the image running inside a VM or is it native?  What is the filesystem involved?  Are you using LVM?  If so, are you working out of a snapshot?

Comment: It's a RAID-1, it's native and I'm using LVM. It looks like those harddrives aren't in RAID and I'm booting from one and sometimes from the other one. This would explain why my changes are gone after reboot but sometimes they come back.

Comment: It is exactly what Avery is suggesting. Your RAID1 config isn't syncing. Review your raid configuration and see.

Comment: That was my suspicion, but without additional information, it's not entirely clear.  bumped +1 for spotting that.